# OpenMP code does not compile with COUT function in #pragma omp target

Tags: c++, gcc, parallel-processing, g++, openmp

I am trying to compile a test code to see if I am able to run external libraries like the std::cout functions in the OpenMP GPU offloaded codes. The code snippet looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(){

        #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
        for (int i=0; i<omp_get_max_threads(); i++)
                std::cout << "Hello World from " << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

After that, I will compile with:

```
/root/offload/install/bin/g++ testgpu.cpp -o testgpu -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none
```

Which will error out with:

```
testgpu.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testgpu.cpp:8:30: error: ‘std::cout’ referenced in target region does not have a mappable type
    8 |                 std::cout << "Hello World from " << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Also, when using other library like the TFHE library, I get a `unresolved symbol...` error.
Are we not able to compile external library functions in the OpenMP Target directive?

Comment: It seems totally normal to me: `omp target` is used to compile the following code on an accelerator (typically a GPU). There is a very high probability your accelerator do not support that because cout is stateful and must be synchronized with the host value. GPUs do not support that. However, this may work with `printf` which is supported on some GPUs (at least Nvidia ones since CUDA support that). Besides this, using `omp_get_max_threads`/`omp_get_thread_num` in such a loop is probably incorrect.

Comment: So is it safe to say that certain libraries might not work in the target directives? @JérômeRichard

Comment: Yes, definitively. For example, there is no chance a network library will not work on GPUs (at least not yet). Even when the code compile, it does not mean it will be efficient. Indeed, using a C++ hash map on current mainstream GPUs would be very inefficient. More generally, writing accelerator-based codes is very different from writing CPU-based codes mainly because accelerators are often specialized for a very specific task. One should keep in mind that although software tools/methods (libraries, runtimes, compilers, etc.) try to close the gap between accelerators and CPUs.